# Safe.pm base_math as math calculator and new variables

Tags: perl

I do not want to write my own recursive-descent math parser or think too deeply about grammar, so I am (re-)using the Perl module [Safe.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/Safe) as an arithmetic calculator with variables.  My task is to let one anonymous web user A type into a textfield a couple of math expressions, like:

```
**Input Formula:** $x= 2;  $y=sqrt(2*$x+(25+$x)*$x); $z= log($y); ...
```

Ideally, this should only contain math expressions, but not generic Perl code. Later, I want to use it for web user B:

```
**Input Print:** you start with x=$x and end with z=$z .  you don't know $a.
```

to <pre> text output that looks like this:

```
**Output Txt:** you start with x=2 and end with z=2.03 .  you don't know $a.
```

(The fact that $a was not replaced is its own warning.) Ideally, I want to check that my web users have not only not tried to break in, but also have made no syntax errors.

My current Safe.pm-based implementation has drawbacks:

- I want only *math* expressions in the first textfield. Alas, `:base_math` only extends Safe.pm beyond `:base_core`, so I have to live with the user having access to more than just math algebra expressions. For example, the web users could accidentally try to use a Perl reserved name, define subs, or do who knows what. Is there a better solution that picks off only the recursive descent math grammar parser?  (and, subs like `system()` should not be permitted math functions!)
- For the printing, I can just wrap a `print "..."` around the text and go another Safe eval, but this replaces `$a` with `undef`. What I really mean my code to do is to go through the table of newly added variables (`$x`, `$y`, and `$z`) and if they appear unescaped, then replace them; others should be ignored.  I also have to watch carefully here that my guys are not working together to try to escape and type text like `"; system("rm -rf *"); print ";`, though Safe would catch this particular issue. More likely, A could try to inject some nasty JavaScript for B or who knows what.

Questions:

1. Is Safe.pm the right tool for the job? Perl seems like a heavy cannon here, but not having to reinvent the wheel is nice.
2. Can one further restrict Safe.pm to Perl's arithmetic only?
3. Is there a "new symbols" table that I can iterate over for substitution?

Answer (score 1):

Safe.pm seems like a bad choice, because you're going to run the risk of overlooking some exploitable operation. I would suggest looking at a parsing tool, such as [Marpa](https://metacpan.org/pod/Marpa::R2). It even has the beginnings of a [calculator implementation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Marpa::R2#A-simple-calculator) which you could probably adapt to your purposes.